# Problem with parentheses and ScriptBaselineShifts

Tags: output-formatting

```
Style[
 DisplayForm@RowBox[{"(", SubsuperscriptBox[2, 6, 7], ")"}],
 18, Bold, ScriptSizeMultipliers -> 1, ScriptBaselineShifts -> {1, 3}]
```

> [image]

or for `ScriptBaselineShifts -> {4, 1}`

> [image]

This is at least undesired effect. I'd like to cut those parentheses just below `6`. Why `ScriptBaselineShifts` affects both limits equally? Is there a walkaround?

Comment: Hm.. Maybe try an `AdjustmentBox`? I have to go now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default rule for spanning characters is to span *symmetrically* above and below the central axis of the whole expression, so in your example `2` is put at the center. To shrink the parentheses asymmetrically, option `SpanSymmetric` needs to be set to `False`:

```
Style[
    DisplayForm@RowBox[{"(", SubsuperscriptBox[2, 6, 7], ")"}],
    18, Bold,
    ScriptSizeMultipliers -> 1,
    ScriptBaselineShifts -> {4, 1},
    SpanSymmetric -> False]
```

[image: asymmetrical parentheses]